# .vmx .vmdk files not opening on VMPlayer

Tags: vmware

I am completing a University Assignment and I copied the .vmx, .vmdk, .vmxf, .vmsd files onto my USB stick from the labs and am working from home.

I installed Ubuntu 14 on my windows 8.01 laptop. I downloaded VMPlayer and clicked 'Open Virtual Machine- open existing virtual machine' and opened the .vmx file from my USB.

It began to open and then the following message appeared.

"The operation on file "/media/charlotte/9675-BE6B/Virtual Disk.vmdk" failed. If the file resides on a remote file system, make sure that the network connection and the server where this disk resides are functioning properly. If the file resides on removable media, reattach the media. Select retry to attempt the operation again. Select cancel to end this session. Select continue to forward the error to the guest operating system."

I was then told by my tutor to move the files onto the hard disk instead of USB. Please could someone tell me how I do this?

Thanks a lot,
Charlotte

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways:

1) Using a terminal

Open a terminal window (press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

In the terminal window which opens by default in your home directory, make a new subdirectory, and then copy the files into the subdirectory

```
mkdir subdirname
cp /media/charlotte/9675-BE6B/*.vm* ~/subdirname
```

Please substitute a directory name that you like, for `subdirname`.  The `~` in the command is a shorthand notation for your home directory.

2) graphically

Open the *File Manager*, either by clicking the icon which appears to be a file cabinet, or by opening the Dash and entering "files"

Right click on the main panel of the file manager, and choose to create a new folder (subdirectory)

In the left panel of the file manager, you will see several commonly used folders, along with 'Computer' and something that will be the entry for your USB drive.  Click on the USB drive, select all the files you need, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.  Click on Home in the left panel to return to your home directory, double click on the subdirectory you created earlier, and right in the main panel to bring up a context menu including the 'paste' command.  Use 'paste' to place copies of your files into the subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked. I managed to open the .vmdk and .vmx on VMPlayer but then this new message appeared.

Comment: "Boot from (hd0,0) ext3 6633d131........
Starting up ...
Loading please wait,
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/6633...... on/root
failed: invalid argument
mount: mounting /root/dev on /dev .static/dev failed: no such file or directory
mount:
mount:
Target: filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= booting

BusyBox v1. 10.2 
Could someone please tell me what this means.

Thanks so much. Charlotte

Comment: This would be more of a separate question - are you trying to install Ubuntu as a guest in VMWare on your Windows 8 machine?

Comment: Yes, i am using VMplayer and trying to open a .vmx

Comment: it is a windows 8 machine and I'm not sure whether i am as a guest or not

Comment: yes its a guest operating system

Comment: I generally tell people that it's much easier to install Ubuntu as a new install in VMWare, than it is to copy a VM from another source.  Do you need to have something specific from this copy of Ubuntu?  A clean installation can be downloaded from [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)